How to pass an object to a constructor where the former becomes part of the instance's data and its getters can reach class specific props and methods
Is it possible to "import" or "pass" a pre-defined object into a class that has access to methods on that class? Importantly, for performance reasons, I need to ensure that I am not re-creating or re-defining the "massive_entity_obj" in the example
class Distinct_Class {
   entities = null;

   constructor(massive_entity_obj) {
      this.entities = massive_entity_obj;
   }

   unique_func_1() {
      const some_value = "calcs based on unique data of Distinct_Class";
      return some_value;
   }
}

// defined in a separate module
massive_entity_obj = {
   property_1: {
      sub_property_a: "something",
      get sub_property_b() {
         // call a function in Distinct_Class in the context of Distinct_Class
         return this.unique_func_1(); // <-- this does not work
      },
   },
};

const distinct_1 = new Distinct_Class(massive_entity_obj)
const distinct_2 = new Distinct_Class(massive_entity_obj)
let sub_prop = distinct_1.entities.property_1.sub_property_b
let other_sub_prop = distinct_2.entities.property_1.sub_property_b


It's not really clear where and how you are instantiating a new Distinct_Class

Is there any significance in sub_property_b being a getter? If yes, which code is accessing it?

tried to clear up how I am trying to use the Distinct_Class

No, this is impossible. When accessing massive_entity_obj.property_1.sub_property_b, it doesn't know anything about distinct_1 or distinct_2 (or that they are distinct)! If you want distinct_1.entities to have different behaviour and different properties (and subproperties) than distinct_2.entities, you must create a different object.

I was afraid I was going about things the wrong way. Thanks for the confirmation.

@Occam ... is the structure of the passed-in object known or are you looking for a generically implemented object-wrapping class-approach for passed-in objects of varying structure/shape?
On the other hand, what is the real reason behind looking for a solution as described by you in the first place? Maybe the entire setting/(pre-)assumptions, leading to an approach like that, are just plainly wrong?

@Occam ... you might have a look at the late provided answer which solves the problem of your introduced scenario entirely generically.

@Peter Seliger thanks for the followup. I am doing my best to avoid any additional overhead. My understanding is the cloning the incoming datablob would be pretty expensive.

Using proxies, I was able to come up with a solution that while does have some additional overhead, it appears to be pretty minimal compared to re-creating an additional getter for each sub_property on each instance of the Distinct_Class

@Occam "My understanding is [that] cloning the incoming datablob would be pretty expensive" - have you actually tried it? How large is the object really? To bind the sub_property_b getter, you only have to clone two objects. I'm pretty sure that has less overhead than using proxies.

@Occam ... Besides of what @Bergi already said about the non-issue regarding performance, the additional advantage/benefit of cloning comes with the 100% disconnection/detachment of any references into the data-blob object that has been passed to the constructor function, which is especially important, in case the object gets used more than once for instantiation. I'm pretty confident that there is hardly a better and more versatile approach than the one I did provide in order to solve your very special use case.

…and last but not least, this looks like a design problem. In good OOP, massive_entity_obj should not have a getter property that depends on some magical context Distinct_Class instance. To provide access to a unique_func_1() implementation, pass it as an argument: massive_entity_obj.property_1.get_sub_property_b(distinct_1). Or maybe the logic shouldn't live in the massive_entity_obj at all, and rather be placed in the Distinct_Class, to be accessed as distinct_1.get("property_1", "sub_property_b") and not via an exposed .entities? (It may internally still dispatch to it).

@Occam ... Regarding the proxy-based approach of yours. If its implementation wants to be as generic/agnostic as mine, you're forced to work recursively through the provided data-blob creating a tree of chained proxy branches, one proxy for each data-node that represent an array/object within the data-blob. In case the data-blob has a fixed structure, the recursive deep-clone solution still is more reliable than the proxy approach for it ensures decoupled/detached references.

@Bergi "To provide access to a unique_func_1() implementation, pass it as an argument" Excellent Point.  I got married to the idea of using a getter as it seemed "cleaner" with my use case for the Distinct_Class, I might need to re-evaluate my design choice.

@Peter Seliger ... thanks for all the help. "the additional advantage/benefit of cloning comes with the 100% disconnection/detachment of any references into the data-blob"  I agree, however, my imported data is intended to be static.  My original hope was essentially "convert" a large object literal (that a user would define) into "class blueprint". It is my understanding that you can't use functions to define the fields of a class in bulk and that is what lead me down this path of trying to import the fields.

@Peter Seliger ... "Regarding the proxy-based approach of yours"  I applied the proxy at the "property" level not the "sub-property" level which dramatically reduced the number of proxies created when loading in the massive object.  While not perfect, it has kept my Class generation time down which was one of my biggest concerns. I accepted your solution as I see it solves the problem I presented in my original post.

@Occam ... Thanks for the clarification. It sounds like your approach indeed leads to another viable solution.

@Occam "you can't use functions to define the fields of a class in bulk" - actually you can, just Object.assign(SomeClass.prototype, objectWithMethods). It even works for getters when you use Object.defineProperties(SomeClass.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(object))

@Bergi ... good point, I was about to address the same. But then again, one still has to deal with the rebinding of the get handlers, regarding the OP'S special use case and data-blob object-structure. There the this of the sub_property_b get handler will never point to the late bound class instance but always to the handler's parent, which for the OP's given example code always is the object referred to by classInstance.entities.property_1. I just changed my example code in order to show the differences of the data-blob's initial and rebound this handling.

What the OP is looking for can be solved entirely generically.
The only assumption one has to make about the to be injected "massive data blob" is that one is going to deal with it as a data structure, where each of this structure's (own) entry (key-value pair), regardless of nested or not, gets treated through its property descriptor.
This setting allows a combined cloning and delegation/binding strategy for getters and setters which are functions, hence their context (the thisArg) can be changed via bind.
Implementing the approach as recursive function, one easily achieves a deep and real clone of any provided data-blob (due to the cloning of property descriptors), whilst also being able of rebinding any getter or setter to the context of the involved class-instance at construction/instantiation time.


// e.g. defined in separate modules

// ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
class DistinctClass {

  #state;
  entities = null;

  constructor(dataBlob, protectedState) {
    this.#state = structuredClone(protectedState);

    this.entities =
      cloneStructureAndRebindAnyGetAndSet(this, dataBlob);

    console.log({
      'injected blob': dataBlob,
      'this.entities': this.entities,
    });
  }
  uniqueDataProcessingMethod() {
    console.log('calcs based on unique instance data/state.');

    return structuredClone(this.#state);
  }
}
// ----- ----- ----- ----- -----

// ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
const massiveDataBlob_1 = {
   property_1: {
      subProperty_A: "sub property A",
      get subProperty_B() {
         // - invocation of a `DistinctClass` instance specific
         //   method within the context of this very instance.
         return this?.uniqueDataProcessingMethod?.() ?? this;
      },
   },
};
// ----- ----- ----- ----- -----

// ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
const massiveDataBlob_2 = {
   property_2: {
      subProperty_C: "sub property C",
      get subProperty_D() {
         // - invocation of a `DistinctClass` instance specific
         //   method within the context of this very instance.
         return this?.uniqueDataProcessingMethod?.() ?? this;
      },
   },
};
// ----- ----- ----- ----- -----

const distinct_A =
  new DistinctClass(massiveDataBlob_1, { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' });

const distinct_B =
  new DistinctClass(massiveDataBlob_2, { baz: 'BAZ', bizz: 'BIZZ' });

const distinctResult_A =
  distinct_A.entities.property_1.subProperty_B;

const distinctResult_B =
  distinct_B.entities.property_2.subProperty_D;

console.log({
  distinctResult_A,
  distinctResult_B,
});
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
function isFunction(value) {
  return (
    typeof value === 'function' &&
    typeof value.call === 'function' &&
    typeof value.apply === 'function'
  );
}

function cloneStructureAndRebindAnyGetAndSet(context, data, result = {}) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {

    result = Array.map(item =>
      cloneStructureAndRebindAnyGetAndSet(context, item)
    );

  } else if (!!data && typeof data === 'object') {

    result = Object

      .keys(data)
      .reduce((target, key) => {

        const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data, key);
        let { set, get, value } = descriptor;
  
        if (isFunction(set)) {
          set = set.bind(context);
        }
        if (isFunction(get)) {
          get = get.bind(context);
        }
        
        if (Object.hasOwn(descriptor, 'value')) {

          if (!!value && typeof value === 'object') {

            value = cloneStructureAndRebindAnyGetAndSet(context, value);
          }
          Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, { ...descriptor, value });

        } else {

          Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, {
            ...descriptor,
            ...(set ? { set } : {}),
            ...(get ? { get } : {}),
          });
        }
        return target;

      }, result);

  } else {

    result = data;
  }
  return result;
}
</script>




I just changed my example code in order to show the differences of the data-blob's initial and rebound this handling.

Not in that way. I know of no good way to give an object and all of its properties access to the functions in a class-defined object like that. Even if the large object was initially made from the class, the object's properties wouldn't have access to the class functions unless the properties' functions were only made using Arrow functions in the constructor of the class.
Your best bet is probably one of two things: you could either make a class with static functions and variables, or create an object from the class in the global scope.
Using static
Making a class with static functions is pretty simple. Using static to define variables and functions basically makes your class into its own object as well as a class. If you want to know more about the static operator, click here. Here is an example:
class myClass {
 static myFunction(value) {
  console.log(value);
 }
}

var myobject = {
 property: {
  a: 'Hello!',
  b: function() {
   myClass.myFunction(this.a);
  }
 }
}

myobject.property.b();

A global object
Creating an object from your existing class which your large object has access to by using a variable would allow for more flexibility, like holding changing variables and acting more like a custom object. Doing so would look like this:
class myClass {
 constructor() {}
    
 myFunction(value) {
  console.log(value);
 }
}

var classobject = new myClass();

var myobject = {
 property: {
  a: 'Hello!',
  b: function() {
   classobject.myFunction(this.a);
  }
 }
}

myobject.property.b();

I would recommend one of these two methods listed above. If, however, you're set on trying to make the existing object and the class mingle without re-creating the object, you could try the way listed below. It just doesn't seem to be made to do it:
Direct access
Albeit, inconveniently given.
The only way that I know that might resemble your code the closest is to assign the new class-made object as a property of each object you want to use the functions in -- which isn't particularly convenient. Only by giving your object's properties an object made by myClass, or calling something like Object.assign(property, new myClass()) on each one would it give them the ability to use the this keyword to access the functions. If you do so, it also seems like you're taking a class and an object and inverting their roles:
class myClass {
 value = 'World';

 constructor(existingobject) {
  existingobject.property.access = this;
 }

 myFunction(value) {
  console.log(`${value}, ${this.value}!`);
 }
}

var myobject = {
 property: {
  a: 'Hello',
  b: function() {
   this.access.myFunction(this.a);
  }
 }
}

new myClass(myobject);
myobject.property.b();

Then, if you want myClass to access myObject, you add something like this.object = existingobject to the Constructor.
I would recommend keeping them separate if possible by using one of the first two suggestions -- especially if a lot of properties and sub-properties are objects in need of using the class' functions.
